# I am facing an issue of "Could not load file or assembly" in mvc core project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

In my local host the project runs fine without any error but when I have deployed the project to the Server there is an issue with one of the assembly files.
The error thrown is :

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Linq.Dynamic.Core, Version=1.2.6.0'. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: There's no such library in .NET. That's an external, third-party library with a misleading name, which has no relation to Microsoft. You need to add the proper NuGet package to your project *and* make sure you copy the third-party DLL to your server. If you publish your project it should appear in the publish folder though

Comment: Instead of using strings for queries, losing most benefits offered by LINQ, consider using LINQ's fluent API to construct queries. Or use eg EF Core's `FromSqlRaw` to execute SQL directly. You're already building queries through strings. With LINQ alone, you can already create an `AND` clause by appending another `,Where()` operation, eg `query=query.Where(cond2);`. You can use libraries like LinqKit to create more complex clauses, like `OR`. With LinqKit you retain type safety and compile-time checks

Comment: Hi ,
I have installed the package from the nuget manager.

Comment: Did you copy the DLLS to the server though? How did you deploy? If you use `dotnet publish` all the necessary DLLs will be included in the `bin/Release.../publish` folder

Comment: I have published all the dlls and it is still  showing me the same error.
I am just wondering why does the local host not throw any error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is providing you the information you need. The assembly of

> System.Linq.Dynamic.Core

was not found, the file is missing. So, if you use a package manager, like NuGet, then you can make sure that the given assembly is properly deployed.

If you do this by hand, then you can find the file on your local computer (where it works), upload it to the server at the appropriate location.

But it's better to manage this automatically, because then you have a more stable deployment phase even for the case when you start working on a new server, etc.